# ubuntu - DDoS по ICMP протоколу

Tags: linux, ubuntu, icmp

На сервере установлен Ubuntu 16.04. Провайдер отключил сервер из-за перенагрузки ICMP протокола. Как можно ограничить входящий на сервер трафик?

Answer (score 1):

> Как можно ограничить входящий на сервер трафик?

никак. сколько прислали пакетов, столько сервер и получит.

Answer (score 1):

Сменить хостера на любого, который предоставляет базовые фильтры от DDoS атак на мощностях своей сетевой инфраструктуры. Таких сейчас полно - REG.RU, Hetzner, OVH и многие другие.

Далее написать собственный правила для IPTABLES, имея представление о легитимном трафике на свой сервер.

Comment: *Далее написать собственный правила для IPTABLES* — и станет приходить меньше пакетов?

Comment: Ну если уж прям стоит задача и не обработанное провайдером порезать, что уж не написать правила IPTABLES для фильтра и не настроить прозрачный прокси в виде промежуточного хоста для нужной машины. Вопрос стоял про ограничение трафика. Никто же не сказал кто именно его должен фильтровать.

Comment: *Никто же не сказал кто именно его должен фильтровать* — логично. тогда, я думаю, надо добавить третьим пунктом про киллеров для спамеров. по-моему, это самое радикальное решение по ограничению входящего трафика.

Comment: Какой вопрос - таков ответ. Что автор имел ввиду под "провайдером" и "сервером" неизвестно. Про киллеров для спамеров - супер.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "1" | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```